# Facebook `find friend box` visibility

Tags: facebook, search

The box is sometimes visible for a friend, as snapshot #1 & #2, and sometimes not visible for another friend, as snapshot #3. I don't know why.

Why is that?

### "Search your friend" box is visible

[image]

[image]

### Not visible for some facebook friends

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your friend in snapshot #3 has prevented you from seeing his/her friend list.

Maybe it is set to `Only Me`

[image: Friend privacy]

Answer (score 0):

> The box is sometimes visible for a friend and sometimes not visible
>   for another friend. I don't know why.
>
> Why is that?

I'm sorry mate but I think I wasn't able to grasp and fully understood your question.

But just my experience in using fb as I am not really active on being there, I am only using the FB official search bar at the top of the page and type **"find friend"** and it will give you the page where you would be able to find some of your other friends through your SNS or mail contacts.

Goodluck FB'ing! :)

Comment: I've added some snapshots to make myself clear. Hope you may get me.